# Does maptiler support DEM .tif images?

Tags: tiles, terrain, cesium, gdal2tiles, maptiler

Does [maptiler](https://www.maptiler.com/) support DEM *.tif images?

I was generating terrain tiles via [cesium-terrain-builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder) but I wonder can I use `maptiler` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

DEM files available in .tif format are considered as simple raster files by all GIS applications. When GIS applications specifically require only DEM files, then they need to check that the .tif files are single band rasters.

You can definitely use maptiler to generate tiles of DEM files.

I recommend you to use GeoserverTerrainProvider.js along with geoserver to serve the terrain tiles in Cesium for 3D rendering.

Comment: My DEM .tif are float,  how thay can be converted to png tiles? (from here https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider `A terrain provider which works with geoserver providing elevation datas in bil, png, gif and jpeg formats.`)

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked it. You can convert and check. If problem is with float values then you can convert to integer using http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116368/converting-raster-file-from-float-to-integer-type-in-arcgis-for-desktop .