# 'Add Colormap' tool returns nothing in ArcGIS Pro 2.2

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, colormap

In QGIS 3, I created a text file for my symbology.
Here it is:

```
symbology.txt

# Fichier d'exportation de palette de couleurs généré par QGIS
INTERPOLATION:INTERPOLATED
0,0,204,170,255,0
8,0,204,170,255,8
16,153,230,0,255,16
24,255,255,0,255,24
32,255,170,0,255,32
40,255,0,0,255,40
80,128,0,0,255,80
```

I apply it to my rasters with singleband pseudocolor symbology.
Here is the result:

[image: raster in QGIS]
[image: symbology in QGIS]

I want to apply this color map file to a raster in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.0.
I modified the file like this:

```
symbology.clr

0    0    204    170    255    0
8    0    204    170    255    8
16    153    230    0    255    16
24    255    255    0    255    24
32    255    170    0    255    32
40    255    0    0    255    40
80    128    0    0    255    80
```

and tried like this too:

```
symbology.clr

0.000000    0    204    170
8.000000    0    204    170
16.000000    153    230    0
24.000000    255    255    0
32.000000    255    170    0
40.000000    255    0    0
80.000000    128    0    0
```

I used « Add Colormap » tool to apply this color map file to a raster. It says that it’s done, but nothing changed..

[image: add colormap tool]

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Does your raster fulfil the requirements as stated in the [usage section](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-colormap.htm#ESRI_USAGES_2DD540579968437EBC92F83455197827) of the tool?

Comment: Indeed ... It is a single band raster but not with integers ... I read this part, but probably too fast ! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Hornbydd said in comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359265/add-colormap-tool-returns-nothing-in-arcgis-pro-2-2#comment587799_359265), my raster did not fulfill the requirements needed to used this tool: the values were not integers.

Some clues if someone got the same problem and want to round pixel values:

for ArcGIS: [Converting raster file from float to integer type in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116368/converting-raster-file-from-float-to-integer-type-in-arcgis-for-desktop)

for QGIS (with gdal): [How to round pixel values of a raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/how-to-round-pixel-values-of-a-raster-in-qgis)